# PHP 7 DomDocument xpath query parent parameter

Tags: php, parent, domdocument, xpathquery

I'm trying to use [eBaysvc.xsd](https://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaysvc.xsd) not only to validate an xml but to build the xml itself:
therefore, passing as $API

> AddDispute

I want to retrieve something like this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddDisputeRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <DisputeExplanation> Tokens </DisputeExplanation>
  <DisputeReason> Tokens </DisputeReason>
  <ItemID> string </ItemID>
  <TransactionID> string </TransactionID>
  <OrderLineItemID> string </OrderLineItemID>
  <Version> string </Version>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken> string </eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <WarningLevel> Tokens </WarningLevel>
</AddDisputeRequest>
```

I built a script using xpath->query that should filter elements according to multiple parameters and so far I got this:

```
$Nodes = $xpath->query('//xs:element[(xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/ebl:CallInfo/ebl:CallName/text()="'.$API.'" or xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/ebl:CallInfo/ebl:AllCalls) and (xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/ebl:CallInfo/ebl:RequiredInput/text()="Yes" or xs:annotation/xs:appinfo/ebl:CallInfo/ebl:RequiredInput/text()="Conditionally")]')
```

but I need to add a further parameter, that is related not to the element but to his Ancestor:

assuming element with `name="ItemID"` we need to add to the query something like
  `and element:parent:parent:parent:parent[@name="'.$API.'Type"]`

since we have this definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="AddDisputeRequestType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Enables a buyer and seller in an order relationship to
            send messages to each other's My Messages Inboxes.
        </xs:documentation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <RelatedCalls>
                AddMemberMessagesAAQToBidder, AddMemberMessageRTQ
            </RelatedCalls>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="ns:AbstractRequestType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ItemID" type="ns:ItemIDType" minOccurs="0">
                    ...
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

but have no idea how to achieve this: can somebody suggest the solution

PS: is there an easier way to check for "Yes|Conditionally" in RequiredInput

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to achieve but this should work `//xs:element[ancestor::*[@name="AddDisputeRequestType"]]` - might need additional work in case of multiple ancestors

Comment: yes, I just need to add `ancestor::*[@name="AddDisputeRequestType"]` to `$xpath->query` argument.
Pls move from comment to answer so I can award you
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access ancestor of some node you could use expression like:

```
//xs:element[ancestor::*[@name="AddDisputeRequestType"]]
```

This expression employs xpath ancestor axis will select all (and any) elements that are ancestors of `xs:element` satisfying the predicate about `name` attribute. You might want to replace asterisk with some more specific element name.

A little bit on `axes` stuff might be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes and here https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#axes

Please beware of some additional care might be needed in case multiple elements match the expression. Here is a short sample on that http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbTj

Update:

> is there a like or contains operand

I think you might use xpath function `contains`, like:

`//*[contains(name(), 'target')]`

what would select all elements that have "target" substring in their name.

This construct pretty much can be used to check text content and attribute names, I've updated a fiddle a bit, you might wanna check it for samples and further fiddling: http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbTj/2 .

And of course you're free to combine whatever you need to do any specific task, like "find all elements with *this* name that have some descendant with *that* name or any descendant with an attribute named *whatever*".

Hope this helps )

Comment: yes, actually I put `xs:complexType` instead of `*`
but have a further question: is there a  `like` or `contains` operand, since I just discovered that `<AllCallsExcept>` can contain multiple values..